# How can i add text to each to each sign wooden object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Wooden sign]

I want to add on each Sign_Wooden_blank_01 2 some text in white. Something nice. For example the first one text will be: To the cave or To The Cave.
Then to add text to the Sign_Wooden_blank_01 2 (1) Sign_Wooden_blank_01 2 (2) Sign_Wooden_blank_01 2 (3) Sign_Wooden_blank_01 2 (4)

Comment: Maybe use a Text component in a world space canvas? You may want to read the Unity documentation on how to display text in-game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Unity` you can right click your **Wooden Sign** in the *Hierarchy* > `3D Object` > `3D Text`. Then you need to adjust your font, size and position of the `Text`.